# A wire of length 100cm is cut into two pieces to form a square and circle. Where should the cut be to minimum the sum of these areas?

Tags: calculus

The total area is $A = \frac{x^2}{4π} + \frac{(100 - x)^2}{16}$. If I set it equal to $0$, I get $x = \frac{200π}{8+2π}$, However the answer states $x = \frac{400π}{4+2π}$. How do I get that? The second derivative test shows that it is indeed a minimum. Do I have to sub my $x$ back into $A$?

Comment: Please show your steps: it is better to have them so that we can pinpoint where the mistake is.

Comment: Your result is wrong. Should be $x=\frac{100 \pi }{4+\pi }$

Comment: is $\frac{200π}{8+2π}$ not equal to that?

Comment: Your answer is the correct solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$A = \frac{x^2}{4π} + \frac{(100 - x)^2}{16}$ So $A'=\frac{x}{2\pi}+\frac{x-100}{8}=0$. So $x=\frac{100\pi}{\pi +4}=43.99..$. Therefore for this $x$, the value of $A$ is minimum

Comment: that was essentially my answer. So the provided solutions must be erroneous

Comment: I also get $x=\frac{100\pi}{4+\pi} = \frac{200\pi}{8+2\pi}$ as an answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the length of wire to be $\ell,$ the side length of our square to be $s,$ and our circle's radius to be $r.$ The equation of constraint relating these values is then given by $$\ell = 4s + 2\pi r$$ because the length of our wire must add up to the perimeters of the square and circle.

The total area for a square and circle is given by the equation $$A = s^2 + \pi r^2.$$ By our equation of constraint,

$$\frac{\ell -4s}{2\pi} =   r$$

$$\text{thus}$$

$$A = s^2 + \pi\bigg(  \frac{\ell -4s}{2\pi}  \bigg)^2= s^2 +  \frac{(\ell -4s )^2}{4\pi} $$

$$\text{implying}$$

$$A'(s) = 2s +  \frac{2(\ell -4s )^1}{4\pi}\;(-4) = 2s -  \frac{2(\ell -4s )^1}{\pi}\; .$$

Setting this equal to zero will give us an expression for the critical points as

$$2s -  \frac{2(\ell -4s )}{\pi}=0$$

$$\text{which implies}$$

$$0=2\pi s -  2\ell +8s =(2\pi + 8)s-2\ell$$

$$\text{and thus}$$

$$s =\frac{2\ell}{(2\pi + 8)} \;.$$

Using $\ell=100$ we have that

$$s =\frac{200}{(2\pi + 8)} \;.$$

The second derivative of $A$ is $$A''(s) = 2-\frac{4}{\pi}>0$$

thus this solution is a minimum. The cut should thus occur at $4s$ so we will have a length $4s\approx 56.00 \text{cm}$ for the square and $\ell - 4s\approx 44.00 \text{cm} $ for the circle.

$\mathbf{EDIT: }$ to clear up any confusion about the correct answer.

At the time of this edit, there are two ideas for what the correct minimizer is. I claim that the minimizer occurs when $$s =\frac{200}{(2\pi + 8)}\approx 14.00 $$

which implies that $$A(s) \approx 14^2 + \frac{(100-(4)(14))^2}{4\pi} \approx 350 \text{cm}^2 \;.$$

The competing opinion is that $$x =\frac{100\pi}{(\pi + 4)}\approx 44.00 $$
where the original poster of that solution was unclear about what $x$ is. $x$ must be the circumference of the circle if it is to be an equivalent (correct) solution.

If you take $x=s$ (which is the mistake I was making in my interpretation of his vague post) then

$$A(s) \approx 44^2 + \frac{(100-(4)(44))^2}{4\pi} \approx 2400 \text{cm}^2 \;$$

which is clearly greater than the true minimum.

Comment: I think you should multiply $s$ to a $\pi $

Comment: Hi @Darman could you please elaborate? Your comment is extremely vague.

Comment: Because you only derivative form $s$. and you ignore the $r$.

Comment: @Darman because we have an equation of constraint, we can reduce this to a problem in one variable (I choose $s$). This is what happens when I plug $r = \frac{\ell -4s}{2\pi} $ into my expression for $A$. This makes it so we don't have to use chain rule.

Comment: Your answer has a mistake. Because I calculated $A$ with my $x$ and the value of $A$ has been smaller than the value of your $A$

Comment: @Darman I believe we've had a bit of a miscommunication. I've cleared things up with my edit.